# Convert geoTIF to ascii/text using R?

Tags: r, image-processing, geospatial

I'm trying to get time-series global estimates of net primary productivity from [here](ftp://ftp.ntsg.umt.edu/pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD17/GeoTIFF/MOD17A3/GeoTIFF_30arcsec/), download them to a remote, US-based machine, machine (I am in Kenya with slow, cell phone internet), convert them from their current format to ascii, coarsen them using a function like this:

```
coarsen = function(input,size_out){
    if (dim(input)[1] != dim(input)[2]) {print("Matrix not square.")} else {    
    dimsize = dim(input)[1]
    fac = dimsize/size_out
    x = suppressWarnings(matrix(c(rep(1, fac), rep(0, dimsize)), dimsize, dimsize/fac))
    t(x) %*% input %*% x}
    }
```

and then download them so that I can work with them.  Is this possible to do using R, rather than a purpose-built GIS program?  If so, how would I do it?  Solutions with R preferred -- I'll be using a cluster that I can't install programs onto, but I can install R packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **raster** package has excellent facilities for reading and writing gridded data in many different formats, and for performing a huge variety of manipulations on such data.

Using it, the basic workflow in your case (for a single file) might be something like this:

```
library(raster)
f <- "path/to/downloaded/file.tif"
r <- raster(f)
ra <- aggregate(r, fact=2)  ## By default aggregates using mean, but see fun=
writeRaster(ra, "path/to/outfile.asc", format="ascii")
```

The package is well documented. I'd suggest starting with `?"raster-package"` and `vignette(Raster)` (plus all of the help files listed in `help(package="raster")`), and then coming back here if you run into serious roadblocks.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work, but it seems to depend on rgdal being installed, which depends on gdal libraries, which I'll have to ask the folks at the supercomputer to install for me (install.packages('rgdal') fails unless you've already got the libraries, it seems.)

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. I should maybe have mentioned in the answer that **raster** borrows most or all of its read/write facilities from gdal by way of **rgdal**.